# Django changed the website name but current_site & activate_url is not changing

Tags: django, django-contrib

I have changed my website name, so I have changed the settings.py file correspondingly.
But my allauth email confirmation message is still sending mails with my old website url.

```
{% load i18n %}{% blocktrans with current_site.name as site_name %}User '{{ user }}' at {{ site_name }} has given this as an email address.

To confirm this is correct, go to {{ activate_url }}
{% endblocktrans %}
```

When I checked with this [post](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/sites/) my current_site is giving my old url name

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
current_site = Site.objects.get(id=settings.SITE_ID)
current_site
```

How to make my current_site & activate_url point to my new website name?

Comment: Have you changed name in `sites` admin (or directly in db table)?

Comment: BTW, better use `Site.objects.get_current()`

Answer (score 0):

I have added the new website name in the admin sites.
The fix for my question is to change the SITE_ID in the settings file.